# Previous image and next image is not working in jquery

Tags: jquery, html

I had downloaded for this code,it is working but When i am clicking the previous and next image that time it is not working,i dont know what will do...$(".pic img").attr("src", "images/Here i want next image src value");

```
<div class="img-box">
  <ul>
    <?php $query1="SELECT * FROM user_photos_offline" ; $sql=mysql_query($query1); $results=array(); while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($sql)){ ?>
    <li>
      <img src="images/cropped-images/<?php echo $row['image']?>" />
      <div class="mask">
        <div class="mag">
          <div class="plus"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </li>
    <?php } ?>
  </ul>
</div>
<div class="full-screen-mask">
  <div class="view-port">
    <div class="pre">
      <span>-</span>
    </div>
    <div class="pic"><img /></div>
    <div class="next">
      <span>+</span>
    </div>

  </div>
  <div class="close">
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
  </div>
</div>


$(".img-box ul li").click(function() {
  var index = $(this).index();
  num = index + 1;
  var img = $(this).find('img').attr('src');
  var index = $(this).index();
  //next button function
  function next() {
    $(".pic img").attr("src", "images/"+num+".png");
  }
  $(".next").click(next);
});



//preview button function
function pre(){ 
    $(".pic img").attr("src","images/pic-"+num+".png");
    num--;
    if(num==0){
        num=8
    }
}


 $(".pre").click(pre);


//next button function
function next(){ 
$(".pic img").attr("src","images/pic-"+num+".png");
num++;
if(num==9){
num=1
    }
}
 $(".next").click(next);
```

Comment: can you share the generated html

Comment: I already shared class name view-port check that one bro...

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE**

```
num = 1;
$(".img-box ul li").click(function() {
  num = $(this).index(); 
  next(); // if you want change pic on click li event
});

$(".next").click(function(){
    next();
});

$(".pre").click(function(){
    pre();
});

//preview button function
function pre(){ 
    //if your src contain all data url
    $(".pic img").attr("src",$('.img-box ul li').eq(num).find('img').attr('src')); // else if not contain all data url $(".pic img").attr("src","images/pic-"+$('.img-box ul li').eq(num).find('img').attr('src')+".png");

    num--;
    if(num==0){
        num=8
    }
}

//next button function
function next(){ 
    $(".pic img").attr("src",$('.img-box ul li').eq(num).find('img').attr('src'));
    num++;
    if(num==9){
        num=1
    }
}
```

**UPDATE 3**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    num = 0;
    $(".img-box ul li").click(function() {
        num = $(this).index(); 
    });

    $(".next").click(function(){
        next();
    });

    $(".pre").click(function(){
        pre();
    });

    //preview button function
    function pre(){ 
        //if your src contain all data url
        if(num==0){
            num=8
        }else{
            num--;
        }
        $(".pic img").attr("src",$('.img-box ul li').eq(num).find('img').attr('src')); // else if not contain all data url $(".pic img").attr("src","images/pic-"+$('.img-box ul li').eq(num).find('img').attr('src')+".png");
    }

    //next button function
    function next(){ 

        if(num==9){
            num=0
        }else{
            num++;
        }
        $(".pic img").attr("src",$('.img-box ul li').eq(num).find('img').attr('src'));
    }
});
```

please see. if you click all link, num is correct. i think is your php function or you image id is incorrect.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  num = 0;
    $(".img-box ul li").click(function() {
        num = $(this).index(); 
  alert(num)
    });

    $(".next").click(function(){
        next();
    });

    $(".pre").click(function(){
        pre();
    });

    //preview button function
    function pre(){ 
        //if your src contain all data url
        if(num==0){
            num=8
        }else{
            num--;
        }
  alert(num)
        //$(".pic img").attr("src",$('.img-box ul li').eq(num).find('img').attr('src')); // else if not contain all data url $(".pic img").attr("src","images/pic-"+$('.img-box ul li').eq(num).find('img').attr('src')+".png");
    }

    //next button function
    function next(){ 

        if(num==9){
            num=0
        }else{
            num++;
        }
  alert(num)
        //$(".pic img").attr("src",$('.img-box ul li').eq(num).find('img').attr('src'));
    }
});
```

```css
body, html{
 cursor:pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="img-box">
    <ul>
   <li>
     <div class="mask">
    <div class="mag">
      <div class="plus">index 0</div>
    </div>
     </div>
   </li>
   <li>
     <div class="mask">
    <div class="mag">
      <div class="plus">index 1</div>
    </div>
     </div>
   </li>
   <li>
     <div class="mask">
    <div class="mag">
      <div class="plus">index 2</div>
    </div>
     </div>
   </li>
   <li>
     <div class="mask">
    <div class="mag">
      <div class="plus">index 3</div>
    </div>
     </div>
   </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="full-screen-mask">
    <div class="view-port">
   <div class="pre">
     <span>-</span>
   </div>
   <div class="pic"><img /></div>
   <div class="next">
     <span>+</span>
   </div>

    </div>
    <div class="close">
   <span></span>
   <span></span>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Not working.when i am clicking next button nothing is happend,check this function name next(), $(".pic img").attr("src","images/pic-"+num+".png"); this one wrong ,$(".pic img").attr("src","images/ i want here next image src value");

Comment: Its not working properly,if i am clicking 1st means it will showed 2nd,like i am cliking 5 th means it will showed 6th image,and also clicking next means showing only 8 images then it will come again 1st image

Comment: ok. just put num = index only without +1. i have modified my update

Comment: Clicking next means it not working properly,two image come correctly,then it will going back

Comment: This time also i am getting same problem,not working what will do now

Comment: Can you put your code with all li no php just pure html please

Comment: I want fetch the value in DB then how will use only html

Comment: No,onclick specific function is not working,then  if i am clicking next image means it show but not working properly i think if condition is something wrong

Comment: It is strange. If you add alert on all statement you can see the num is correct. When you Click plus or minus the function work correctly. What the issue now?

Comment: When i am click plus means showing 2 image then it wil going before image